# Improper Prior Distribution

Tags: bayesian

What is the clear mathematics definition about improper prior distributions? Can you give me some book or article links about it?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prior_probability#Improper_priors

Answer (score 2):

Degroot & Schervish *Probability and Statistics* (4th ed.) Def. 7.3.2

> Improper Prior. Let ξ be a non-negative function whose domain includes the parameter space of a statistical model. Suppose that $\intξ(θ)dθ = ∞$. If we pretend as if ξ(θ) is the prior p.d.f. of θ, then we are using an improper prior for θ.

Other:

- The entire section of 7.3 on improper priors in Degroot & Schervish
  (see above)
- Jeffreys Prior: Section 5 [here](http://www.stat.duke.edu/~st118/sta250/priors.pdf) & "The Jeffreys Prior"
  mid-section [here](http://stat.duke.edu/courses/Fall11/sta114/jeffreys.pdf) (contain good information about improper priors in general as well)
- Hoff's *A First Course in Bayesian Statistical Methods* on pp. 78-79 (1st ed.) chapter 5

There are other books & articles out there but I'm not familiar enough with them to hand out a recommendation

Comment: An improper prior density is a nonintegrable prior density. The nonintegrable density can be an infinite measure that is countably additive (as stated). Another possibility is that it is a finitely additive probability measure assigning zero to all subsets of the parameter space.